# Slider for bootstrap with multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

When it comes to Javascript, I'm somewhat a complete beginner. Having Python behind me, I somewhat understand a little of what's going on.  I have been using [this library](http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/), which is a bootstrap slider (now I'm not referring to a carousel, thats a completely different thing), this is a slider for an input form.

My issue is, that I'm dynamically outputting a form from a Django model, and in this form it could potentially have several of these sliders all going at once.

According to the docs that come with [bootstrap-slider](http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/), the following code will allow you to pass the value of the slider to the DOM when the slider is moved.

```
###################
       HTML
###################

<input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/&t
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>


###################
    JavaScript
###################

// With JQuery
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});

// Without JQuery
var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});)
```

Now, the problem that's causing me such a big issue, is the way I've had to code this because of Django.

```
{% for field in filter.field_set.all %}
    <input id="slider-{{ field.pk }}" name="{{ field.filter.title }}" data-slider-id='{{ field.pk }}Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="{{ field.min }}" data-slider-max="{{ field.max }}" data-slider-step="{{ field.step }}" data-slider-value="{{ field.min }}" data-for="slider_value_{{ field.pk }}" data-slider-orientation="vertical"/>
    <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="slider_value_{{ filter.pk }}">3</span></span>
{% endfor %}
$('[id^=slider-]').slider();
$(this).on("slide", function (slideEvt){
    value = this.data('for');
    changer = $(value);
    changer.text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

I'm totally baffled as to how to approach this. What I'm trying to do, is get the span with the id that's defined in data-slider-label to change the .text value to what the `slideEvt.value` is.

Comment: changer is the span with id=slider_value_{{ filter.pk }}

Comment: Updated my answer. I think it should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

First of all, you'll need to make sure that the value of `data-for` of an `input` and the `id` of the `span` associated with it are same. Because that is how you will know which `span` to change.

So, change the `span` like this:

```
<span id="slider_value_{{ field.pk }}">3</span>
```

Note: If, however, you don't want to change the `span`'s `id`, you can change the value of `data-for` to `slider_value_{{ filter.pk }}`. Just remember, both should match.

Now the JavaScript/jQuery part

```
$('[id^=slider-]').slider();

$('[id^=slider-]').on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    changer_span = $(this).attr('data-for');
    $('#' + changer_span).text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

Comment: No. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ the # is not required in an attribute contains selector.

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman, Yeah, sorry about that. :P I've updated the answer.

Comment: The problem is not with initiating the slider. `$('[id^=slider-]').slider();` works just fine.  The problem is getting the value to update in the correct span within the slide event function. How do I get the data-slider-label attribute from within the slide event?

Comment: works a treat, and now I understand the `this` selector a little better. thanks!